# Boot Desktop PC with RPi - is it possible?

Tags: raspbian, boot, windows

I’m planning to rebuild my desk and with it, there will be a monitor lift and hopefully a RPi to control it via button or voice.

In my dreams, I’m able to put on a second button for the power on of the real PC behind the scenes.
Is it possible to attach a second power-on-cable but let the raspberry trigger it? Primarily for the basic implementability. I’m just in the inventing- and figuring-mode for now.

I’ve got to admit, I’m a newbie by all means and don’t know much - but I’m here to stay.
I still hope, that it’s the correct forum.

Answer (score 2):

You could cut into the leads from the PC's power button, and use a relay attached to a GPIO pin to switch them. Since most PC power buttons are momentary switches (at least for power on - the "hold for 10 seconds to shut down" is different, of course!), that should work as far as I know. There may be other complications, but I'm pretty sure you wouldn't blow up the power supply or motherboard by doing that.